# Configure a Bridge Device in CentOS 7 via Kickstart

Tags: kickstart, centos7, rhel7

I wish to configure a br0 bridge with kickstart using eth0 as its slave.

Is this possible?

I have not seen any kickstart examples that do this.

I wish to use this box as a KVM host, so I'm looking to setup bridging (not bonding)

Comment: There appears to be no specific options in the default network setup, but there is always room for custom script work in the post install section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of CentOS 7.1 you can use the --bridgeslaves option to add slave interfaces to a bridge, for example:

```
network --device=br0 --bridgeslaves=em1,em2
```

Note that this doesn't work in CentOS 7.0. If you try it will throw an 'unsupported option' error.